# What's the correct way to submit 2 versions of an iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have the following scenario:

- already have a free app with ads on app store
- wanna submit a paid version including new features and without ads
- wanna keep the free option with ads

What would be the best approach to do this? Should I create another app bundle id for the paid app and just update the free one with the same bundle id?

Comment: Why not an In App Purchase to remove ads and include the new features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the app you already have, you just have to add a new target (duplicate it).

Select your project in the `Project Navigator` and select your projects target by right clicking:

[image]

Next you have to set a new `Bundle ID`, `Version` and `Build` number.

Each target is a single app which needs to set up an App inside `ITunesConnect`.
When uploading your app, you just have to select the target you want at the top of xCode:

[image]

Programmatically you can make changes just for a specific `Bundldeidentifier` by using this snippet:

```
if([[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]    
        isEqualToString:@"[Bundle id]"]){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An other option would be In App Purchase, which would allow you to have the exact same version on AppStore.

You just simply unlock the paid features if the user bought your app and hide the ads. You should consider this approach, if you want to migrate data from the free version to the paid one ( a database, settings, user generated stuff, etc ).

Answer (score 1):

In terms of **project**, you **should have the same project with 2 different `target`**.

In terms of **AppStore**, **yes, are 2 different app** (one for each target).